# C#: XML transformation

Tags: c#, .net, html, xml, xslt

I have an XML-file with known structure, but I can't change anything on it.
The task is to show data from this XML in browser (C# WebBrowser control) perhaps as html using some style sheet.

The question is how I could apply transform on existing XML without inserting anything like

```
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="my-style.xsl"?>
```

I'm thinking of copy an XML somewhere, then add this xml-stylesheet and then show it in browser. But maybe I can dynamically apply style-sheet somehow?

Maybe it's possible to hold an XML in memory, apply style-sheet, and load in-memory xml to WebBrowser control?

I'm just wondering what is the best way for doing this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you can! Look at [`XslCompiledTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx) class. So you can transform your XML in memory, then load transformed document.

Comment: Could you please give me an example how to output transformed xml into browser? Using Stream or XmlWriter?

Comment: Hmm.. looks like my WebBrowser doesn't show data... Really strange! When I use MessageBox.Show() then I can see the page, but after message closed, it's invisible again :(

Answer (score 0):

**See the XSLT transformation used by [the XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html) to produce HTML-formatted XML document**.

Alternatively you can also have a look at IE's defaultss.xsl stylesheet, but be aware that it uses a non-standard dialect of XSLT -- strictly speaking not XSLT at all.